# how to run one or group of tests repeatedly in Go Test IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, go, intellij-plugin

From time to time I have this annoying tests with intermittent issues, that I need to run many times to expose. I was looking for a convenient way to set a number or "endless loop" from the intelliJ, but I did not find.

Is there a plugin or I missed something that could allow me to do this from the UI (instead of changing code for it).

EDIT: As I found the support for such feature is per test utility plugin. For example, it already exists for JUnit, but there is no such for Go Test. My instinct suggests that such functionality should be generically provided for all test plugins, but there might be some technical reasons for per plugin approach.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the Run Configuration of the test there is a "Repeat:" dropdown where you can specify the number of repeats, for example until the test fails. I believe this is available since IntelliJ IDEA 15.

Comment: Oh, I see it in the jUnit tab. It did not occur to me that something like this might be test type related implementation - that I find as a strange decision anyways. I am using intelliJ with go and I was looking for such for Go Test. It seems that for this I need to request a plugin change.

Comment: Note that it doesn't appear in modify options of run configuration when running tests using gradle. But running test config can be switched to use intellij in settings > build, execution, deployment > build tools > gradle > run tests using: "Intellij IDEA". Then the option appears

Answer (score 4):

based on @Bas Leijdekkers comment

**IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2**

Right click on test class or test -> More Run/Debug -> Modify Run Configuration... ->
[image]

Modify options -> repeat

[image]

select N times

[image]

"Repeat count:" will appear now just apply and u r free to go :)

Comment: Note that it doesn't appear in modify options of run configuration when running tests using gradle. But running test config can be switched to use intellij in settings > build, execution, deployment > build tools > gradle > run tests using: "Intellij IDEA". Then the option appears

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use oracle JDK to create a executor service which schedules the running /execution of the test suite periodically unless you shut down the service 

Please have a look at the below oracle doc 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Sample 

 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```